# Form resubmits on page refresh

Tags: python, django

My form resubmits every time I refresh the page. I want to send context with my render

```
if request.method == 'POST' and 'search_form' in request.POST:

    rol = request.POST['rol']
    group = request.POST['group']
    national_number = request.POST['national_number']
    phone_number = request.POST['phone_number']

    users = MyUser.objects.filter(Q(group__name=group)|Q(role__name=rol)|Q(national_number=national_number)|Q(phone_number=phone_number))
    return render(request,'deletuser.html',locals())
```

Comment: This is exactly why you must always redirect after a successful POST.

Comment: @DanielRoseman because I want show result in same page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you directly render a page as the result of a POST, then refreshing that page will resubmit the form, because that's how you got there.

The usual way to avoid this is to issue an HTTP redirect after a POST, instead of rendering content directly.  Then the user ends up on a page via GET, which can be refreshed without problems.

You can google search for "redirect after post" to get more details.

Comment: do you have any way with post method that not resubmission ?